# Data on sharing / suggesting / inviting behaviours on mobile

Tags: user-behavior, research, data, sharing

I am researching patterns of sharing / inviting / suggesting behaviours of users on mobile apps.

I can imagine they differ by

- channel (facebook, whatsapp, instagram, email, sms etc),
- content (news, check-in, organization etc),
- community (family, friends, colleagues, strangers etc)

But I could not find any data on that. Can anyone suggest any further reading?

Answer (score 1):

Sharing, inviting and suggesting are all social activities so I'd would start with broad strokes from Social Theory and Activity Theory.

In addition you could check studies on marketing and how / why people suggest products to each other (word-of-mouth is known to have an effect on how people review the product, [for example](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/014829639400047I)).

There is one Finnish article on how social UX affects people using web services, such as Facebook. It's probably not what you're looking for but take a look.

[Identifying drivers and hindrances of social user experience in web services](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1753704)

I think you should also take a look at interaction-design.org's article on [Social Computing](https://www.interaction-design.org/encyclopedia/social_computing.html).

> Thus when we speak of social computing we are concerned with how digital systems go about supporting the social interaction that is fundamental to how we live, work and play. They do this by providing communication mechanisms through which we can interact by talking and sharing information with one another, and by capturing, processing and displaying traces of our online actions and interactions that then serve as grist for further interaction.

Answer (score 0):

This is part psychology, part UX, part Marketing. Our friend above already provided good starting points around Social Theory and Activity Theory. Besides, [this academic paper](http://www.anderson.ucla.edu/faculty/suzanne.shu/Shu%20Carlson%20Three%20in%20Persuasion.pdf) about "Identifying the Optimal Number of Claims in Persuasion Settings" is a great read.

Regarding UX, I did my fair bit of research last year while working with a few startups hands-on. The bottom line is summarized in the following articles: I wrote a [piece about channels, mechanisms and mobile](http://andreehuk.com/post/104760066502/user-growth-on-mobile-apps-inviting-friends-best) a little while ago. After the post a friend integrated a sharing mechanism outlined in the post in their app sign-up flow and increased sign-ups by 1023%. Besides, I wrote [another piece](http://andreehuk.com/post/70300458988/engage-or-go-home-how-to-avoid-the-cliff-after) last year and put the bottom line into a [talk](https://vimeo.com/97742211) thereafter. 
Please excuse the bit of (shameless) self-promotion but your post above hits the questions' nail on its head. Feedback welcome.

Regarding the marketing part that I mentioned above [this Growth Hacking ebook](https://markstaton.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/the-definitive-guide-to-growth-hack.pdf) will provide you with a few more hints as to what to look for and where to dig deeper. It is overall a good read. They a few other ebooks that might be worth your while.